# What does salt do to styes?

Tags: physiology, eyes, human-eye

Styes formed in the eyes are cured by dabbing at them with lukewarm water(I saw this being done many a times as a home remedy.) At times, common salt is added to the water before dabbing. My mother says, NaCl hastens the healing process; why is it so? What does salt do to cure the styes faster? Can salt be used for treating other eruptions anywhere else?

Comment: Same reason as this http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/189/why-does-salt-water-help-sore-throats

Comment: Is there no difference between the cause for sore throat and that for sty formation? I guess there is. So, I wonder how the reasons for salt healing both can exactly be the same. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: Stye is caused due to infection by micro-organisms. So the same theory applies. Salt water does not discriminate between organisms